# Hex string to struct containing double, float, integer

Tags: python, struct, hex, byte

```
struct_format = "<ddddfIHHH"
```

I have my input data file like this:

```
28b6 b33 157b 3fd8 6791 1510 31df 3fe3 90d8 d063 40c 3fd8 e8cb 23ed 23fb bfe3 0 0 0 0 1111 2222 3333
```

I want to parse it as `"<ddddfIHHH"`, with the desired output being `0.376311 0.599838 0.375247 -0.598142 0.000000 0 4369 8738`.

Here are the problems I've encountered:

I want it to unpack as double for suppose and from the input I have to read `3fd8157b0b3328b6` to get the output `0.376311`.

But how can I read from a file in reverse order? And I have to pad zeros to `b33` because my word length should be 4 to use the `bytes.fromhex()` function. And I have to repeat this process. Next I mentioned double, so I have to read `3fe3 31df 1510 6791` like this.

Comment: First, I would split the input at spaces. Then I would convert each part to a 16-bit integer. Then I would combine these in the correct order to a `bytes` object, which I would then pass to `struct.unpack` with the given format.

Comment: I tried in that way but i have to read data from a file in reverse order

Comment: No, you don't have to. You can read the data from the file in normal order and then put it together in the right order afterwards.